# Field Field name `test` is not valid for model `Ability`

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model without field 'test'. I'm assigning this field in runtime:

```
ability = Ability.objects.first()
ability.test = 'TEST!!'
```

I also have the serilizer:

```
class AbilitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ability
        fields = ('name', 'test',)
```

And when I use it:

```
return Response(AbilitySerializer(ability).data)
```

I'm getting error:

```
Field Field name `test` is not valid for model `Ability`.
```

**EDIT**: I'm still facing this issue when I'm passing array of objects to serializer (with many=True). It's OK when I pass single instance.

Why and how to fix it?

Comment: add a field with name 'test' in your serializer class before class Meta:

Answer (score 2):

As Ajay Gupta indicated, non-model fields/methods/properties must be explicitly declared:

```
class AbilitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # read_only since test is not a model field
    test = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Ability
        fields = ('name', 'test',)
```

Additionally, if you do not always provide `test`, consider:

```
test = serializers.CharField(required=False, read_only=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for single instance. But it doesn't work for many instances (take look at edited post)